# Marque Rss news feed inside my android app

Tags: android

I am new to android.I am creating an application and inside that application i am thinking of putting a 'marque Rss feed' at bottom of the activity.Is it possible? Is it possible to put more then two RSS feed in the same activity?

Comment: I would recommend taking a look at ViewPager in the Android support library, and then this pretty awesome library: http://viewpagerindicator.com/

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible..

Here is the code To fetch a RSS Feed from a URL and list it in a listview in android.

You need first to create a class that extends ListActivity, and then put this code:

```
    // Initializing instance variables
    headlines = new ArrayList();
    links = new ArrayList();

    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://www.RSS-Feed-URL-HERE");

        XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
        factory.setNamespaceAware(false);
        XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

            // We will get the XML from an input stream
        xpp.setInput(getInputStream(url), "UTF_8");

            /* We will parse the XML content looking for the "<title>" tag which appears inside the "<item>" tag.
             * However, we should take in consideration that the rss feed name also is enclosed in a "<title>" tag.
             * As we know, every feed begins with these lines: "<channel><title>Feed_Name</title>...."
             * so we should skip the "<title>" tag which is a child of "<channel>" tag,
             * and take in consideration only "<title>" tag which is a child of "<item>"
             *
             * In order to achieve this, we will make use of a boolean variable.
             */
        boolean insideItem = false;

            // Returns the type of current event: START_TAG, END_TAG, etc..
        int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            if (eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {

                if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {
                    insideItem = true;
                } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
                    if (insideItem)
                        headlines.add(xpp.nextText()); //extract the headline
                } else if (xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("link")) {
                    if (insideItem)
                        links.add(xpp.nextText()); //extract the link of article
                }
            }else if(eventType==XmlPullParser.END_TAG && xpp.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("item")){
                insideItem=false;
            }

            eventType = xpp.next(); //move to next element
        }

    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Binding data
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, headlines);

    setListAdapter(adapter);


}
public InputStream getInputStream(URL url) {
       try {
           return url.openConnection().getInputStream();
       } catch (IOException e) {
           return null;
         }
    }

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
   Uri uri = Uri.parse((String) links.get(position));
   Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
   startActivity(intent);
}
```

& You can also make the class extends Activity, and manually put two listviews in the activity & then handle this code to be for the two listViews.

Comment: Thanx...i will try this and letb you know :)